# iOS 13 modality support

Tags: react-native

react native supports the new Modality feature from iOS 13 ?

UIModalPresentationAutomatic
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/modality/
https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e

Comment: https://twitter.com/satya164/status/1142786047245467649